# Unable to ge the counts using GROUP BY mysql

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

Here is my Table Structure:

```
session_id | session_name |  celebrity_id | charity_id | created_date
```

I want to get the total count of celebrity_id that are associated with a charity_id. Now here is a thing that a celebrity_id can come in the table multiple times against the same charity_id here is the SQL i wrote here `$member_id` is charity id i am providing in my PHP script:

```
SELECT COUNT(celebrity_id) AS count 
FROM sessions
WHERE chairty_id = $member_id
GROUP BY celebrity_id,charity_id
```

but it returns me many rows rather returning just one count.

Comment: u doun`t need group by celebrity_id

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
SELECT COUNT(celebrity_id) AS count 
FROM sessions
WHERE chairty_id = $member_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use  `GROUP BY` <strike>`celebrity_id`</strike>

```
SELECT COUNT(celebrity_id) AS count 
FROM sessions
WHERE chairty_id = $member_id
```

<strike>GROUP BY charity_id</strike>

HTH

EDIT: @Veekay nailed it, you don't need to group at all.